# Getting Error with an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting an error when running this query in SQL Server 2008:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp 
       "select Row_ID, Service_Code,Skill from Account_Service" 
       queryout "d:\text.txt" -c -T -x'
```

Error is:

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>   SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
>   SQL Server Books Online.
>   SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]
>   Login timeout expired

[image]

**NOTE**: `Shared Memory`, `Named Pipes`, `TCP/IP` are all **enabled** in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Can you connect to the instance using Management Studio?

Comment: **NOTE**: `Shared Memory`, `Named Pipes`, `TCP/IP` are in **Enabled** status in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: @OMGPonies: Yes, I'm able to connect to the instance with Management Studio

Comment: Can you login/connect using the same login name/password as your program? It's not a case of a login being disabled?

Comment: @Paddy: I'm able to connect with the same credentials. Not getting why the query is throwing error. How to resolve this issue/error.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the SQL Configuration Manager.
I guess TCP/IP Protocoll is not enabled, so you can Access your SQL Server via. Shared Memory.
So you would be able to Connect if you are on the SQL Server it self but can not Access it from another Maschine.

Otherwise I would say it is an Network Problem as you see the Connection times out. Maybe a Firewall Software is blocking or your Server can not be reached.

The most likely Cause I expririenced, fitting to oyur discrition is disabled TCP/IP Protocol for SQL Server.

Comment: Pls refer in the **NOTE**. I'm Enabled TCP/IP. But still NOT working. No firewall issue or network problem.